# Dynamic Module Loading after Login in Prism

Tags: wpf, prism

In my prism application module is loading when shell is loaded. But I want to load module after my login, so that I can load module base on role types. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/blagunas/archive/2013/08/06/prism-dynamically-discover-and-load-modules-at-runtime.aspx

Comment: if it is not hard to you could you show how you managed to load a module dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the attribute provided in Justin's answer, to manually load modules you need to be using the IModuleManager and use the LoadModule method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: So is it enough just writing `[Module(ModuleName = "test", OnDemand = true)]` to load modules dynamically?

Comment: Maybe you have a link where it is possible to see Dynamic loading of modules using this Attribute?

Comment: It is not enough just writing Module(ModuleName = "test", OnDemand = true). we have to do in LoadModule.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can override GetModuleCatalog method in the Bootstrapper. Also you need to add 
OnDemand=true attribute

```
[Module(ModuleName = "test", OnDemand = true)]
public class test: IModule
{

}
```